# Как мне поместить DataSet в DataContext?

Tags: c#

Вот мой DataContext:

```cs
DataContext dataContext = new DataContext(connectionString);
```

Вот мой DbSet:

```cs
DataSet ds = new DataSet(connectionString);
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   var List = db.Query<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type in (N'U')").ToList();
   foreach (dynamic Table in List)
   {
     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(Table.name);
     var ListColumn = db.Query<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS").Where(b => b.TABLE_NAME == Table.name).ToList();
     foreach (dynamic el in ListColumn)
     {
        DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn();
        dataColumn.ColumnName = el.COLUMN_NAME;
        if (el.DATA_TYPE == "int")
        {
           dataColumn.DataType = typeof(int);
        }
        else if (el.DATA_TYPE == "nvarchar")
        {
           dataColumn.DataType = typeof(string);
        }
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
     }
     ds.Tables.Add(dataTable)
  }
}
```

Как мне поместить DataSet в DataContext?

Comment: DataSet в конструкторе принимает _имя_. Конечно, можно в качестве имени задать любое значение, даже _строку соединения_, но смысла в этом мало.

Comment: `db.Query` - откуда этот метод, из какой библиотеки? Dapper? Укажите _все_ используемые технологии (добавьте метки и опишите в теле вопроса).

Comment: Что значит "поместить DataSet в DataContext"? Смысл этой фразы совершенно непонятен. Вы хотите на лету создать модель (entity - сущность) EF? Это невозможно. Вы хотите скопировать данные откуда-то куда-то? Уточните, откуда и куда. И на кой ляд для этого использовать **три разные** технологии, когда достаточно одной?

Comment: Во втором запросе `SELECT *` считывает **все** данные из таблицы. Затем, уже на клиенте, вы фильтруете эти данные с помощью метода `Where`. Такой подход _очень_ неэффективен. Фильтрацию нужно делать в БД.

Answer (score 2):

Никак.

Вы смешиваете две технологии: Entity Framework (верхняя строка DataContext), в котором используется описание схемы базы данных в миграциях и/или коде и ADO, в котором вы пишете plain sql запросы. И это не просто смешение, а попытка воткнуть треугольный штекер в круглый разъём: оно не предназначено для этого и вероятно просто сломается, т.к. слишком разнородное.

Гипотетически, может быть и можно хитрым способом подменить знатную часть EF'а собственными штуками, но это будет такой костыль и грубый хак, что лучше не стоит пытаться усидеть на двух стульях: у вас либо структура базы описана в строгих классах (EF) либо заранее неизвестна (ADO). Не знаю, сколько тысяч человеко-часов вложила майкрософт в EF, но если вы хотите переизобрести EF - ну, попробуйте.

Но попытки вероятно потребуют немало человеко-часов от вас и будет падать при малейшем обновлении пакетов (кстати, вы не указали - у вас EF или EF Core, но в принципе, разницы особой нет), а также сбоить в каких-то неожиданных сценариях типа обновления detached сущностей.

И да, если вы видели методы `.Add()` и `.Attach()` у DbSet — они не делают то, что вам нужно, это для другого.